# Link target _system is not working on IOS inAppBrowser

Tags: ios, hyperlink, target, inappbrowser

I have an Angular/Java Spring web project. As part of the project, it was necessary to create an Android and iOS application.

To simplify the task, I chose to develop an Ionic Capacitor application where we run our website within an in-app browser. So far, no issues, everything works fine, but I'm facing difficulties with external links specifically on iOS.

```
openGmail(): void {
    const emailSubject = 'Subject';
    const emailBody = 'body.';
    const gmailLink = `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=${encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com')}&su=${encodeURIComponent(emailSubject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(emailBody)}`;
    window.open(gmailLink, '_system');
}
```

The '_system' target doesn't seem to work: 'window.open(gmailLink, '_system');' doesn't work.

I would like to achieve the same behavior as on Android and get the link to open as expected.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and can tell me how to make the link work? Is there a specific target for iOS?